# Xoom compatibility issues

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I posted a while back about tablet compatibility problems, and was told to add the Galaxy Tab addon as my build target.  This made the app work fine on the emulators, and I've had one Xoom download the app, but I've got someone currently trying to download the app who is unable to...

When he tries to download, the market blocks him and says the app isn't compatible.  He says he's downloaded other apps with no problems, but this one won't work.  The only difference he's noticed is this: "You know there is a screen that pops up after clicking buy app that list all functions the app uses. Most apps I see utilize more functions. Such as memory, and other items in the list. The cross country score keeper app says uses no specific  functions. I wonder if that's the issue.."

Does anyone know which end this problem is on?  I'd really like to get the app out to him, but none of the fixes I've been trying have opened it up to him...

The specs of the Xoom being used: Motorola xoom tablet with honeycomb 3.1 kernel 2.6.36.3

The user reports that when he tries to download the app from the web-based market, he gets a message saying that it's incompatible with his Xoom.

He can only view the app  in the device-based market via a link which he emailed to himself, but he still gets a non-compatibility message...

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.bjpcomet.XCScore"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>  
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.ScoringApp"
                  android:label="@string/main_title">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.Setup"
              android:label="@string/setup_title">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.RunMeet"
            android:label="@string/main_title">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.SetupMenu"
            android:label="@string/setup_title">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.ColorSettings"
              android:label="@string/setup_title">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.ColorPicker"
              android:label="@string/setup_title">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did the user try to download using the Android Market on the device or the web-based Android Market (i.e., pushing the app to the device)? Also, is the user running a 3.0 Xoom or 3.1? As one of the users who downloaded your app for the Xoom running 3.1, I can confirm that it is possible for that device.  One other thing would help - the <uses-sdk> element from your manifest.

Comment: In default.properties I have: "target=Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.:GALAXY Tab Addon:8." Is the targetSdkVersion 8 OK, or is there a more specific target to go along with th Tab addon?  Don't THINK that would cause these problems, but may as well make sure I'm doing it right!

Comment: Are there specific features of the Galaxy Tab (e.g., the front-facing camera), that your app is using?  I can't recall from the original question why the Galaxy Tab add-on was being used.

Comment: no specific features, the only hardware used is touchscreen, and a small bit of data storage. The initial question was 'What do I need to do to make the program Tablet/Xoom-compatible,' but the new question seems to be 'Why does it only work for SOME Tablets/Xooms, and how can I fix that?'

Comment: Yes... that is a stickier question.  There's a discussion here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158354/how-will-using-the-samsung-galaxy-tab-add-on-affect-fetter-my-android-market-depl) that would indicate that the add-on shouldn't be necessary and, in any case, wouldn't be necessary for the Xoom.  The only other reason that comes to mind for why the user wouldn't be able to install would be if you had previously given him/her a Beta or Development version signed with a different key and that version hadn't been uninstalled.

Comment: I see mention that Samsung "suggests" a minimum SDK version of 4. Could the min sdk of 1 potentially be the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be; if it was going to be a factor, it wouldn't even indicate that the device was compatible in the Android Market (which it still does at this point).  It will be interesting to see what the user has to say, in particular, when he says the Market is "blocking" him, whether it's the web-based Market or the one on the device.

Comment: (I've added the requested information)

Comment: Found some similar posts, tried changing the copy protection settings, that did the trick!

Comment: Ahh... I haven't played with copy protection, so that didn't occur to me.  You might want to post your solution as an answer to your question, so that other people can easily find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem--it was in the copy protection setting.  I had it enabled, and apparently it's been known to cause some problems with app visibility on the market for certain devices.  All you have to do to fix it is disable the copy protection

Google recommends using their newer licensing service instead. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html